# Error running weathercan package - fatal SSL/TLS alert (e.g. handshake failed))

Tags: r, ssl, dplyr, purrr, handshake

I am running the "weathercan" data package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/weathercan/index.html; https://github.com/ropensci/weathercan) and keep getting an error when trying to retrieved data from the Environment and Climate Change historic weather data website. I've re-installed the package, I even reinstalled R and RStudio after deleting everything R from my system, but the error persists.

The package works fine when I look up stations up, e.g.,

> stations_search(coords = c(44.140125, -80.363136), dist = 20, interval = "day")

I get:
[image]

But whenever I try to retrieve data I get an error. For example:

> Station_data <- weather_dl(station_ids = 4497, start = "2000-01-01", end = "2002-05-30", interval = "day")

Returns:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `html`. x schannel: next
> InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) -
> This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g.
> handshake failed). i Input `html` is `purrr::map(...)`.

[image]

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred, give this:

> <error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
> Problem with `mutate()` input `html`.
> x schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE
> (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is
> received (e.g. handshake failed). i Input `html` is `purrr::map(...)`.
> Backtrace:
>
> 1. weathercan::weather_dl(...)
> 2. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
> 3. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call)) Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

This is all beyond my understanding, so I'm stuck here.

Any insights would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Update 2020-10-17]

This solution has also been reported on the [weathercan issue](https://github.com/ropensci/weathercan/issues/104#issuecomment-711069917)

It looks like [curl](https://jeroen.cran.dev/curl/) uses two SSL backends for Windows: OpenSSL and Windows Secure Channel. By default curl uses the Windows Secure Channel which is supposed to be best, but doesn't quite have the full functionality of OpenSSL ([more details](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/windows.html)).

My best guess is that something changed on the ECCC server that required a functionality not provided by Windows Secure Channel. When I forced my windows testing platform (AppVeyor) to use OpenSSL I had no more problems.

If you would like to try this, you'll have to add the following to your .Renviron file (which is loaded during R's startup):

`CURL_SSL_BACKEND=openssl`

If you're unsure how to edit your .Renviron file, you can use the usethis package to find/create and open it for you (restart R afterwards):

```
install.packages("usethis")
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

**Disclaimer**: I don't think there are security drawbacks for doing this, but I'm not a network specialist by any stretch!

---

[Original Answer]

I'm the developer of the [weathercan](https://docs.ropensci.org/weathercan/) package. Unfortunately I have some details for you but not exactly a solution.

I've been trying to track down the origins of this problem. From what I can see it's actually problem between R and the ECCC server, which (so far) only seems to crop up on Windows, but not for everyone (I run Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 and can't reproduce it, but others on Windows 10 and 8 have run into the problem).

You can follow the discussion in a reported issue, here: https://github.com/ropensci/weathercan/issues/104

The reason why we think this isn't strictly a weathercan issue is because if users with this problem try to download an ECCC file directly, e.g.,

`read.csv("https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=51097&timeframe=1&submit=Download%2BData&Year=2020&Month=10")`

they run into a similar problem (and `read.csv()` is a function from the utils package).

Comment: Hi Dr. LaZerte, thanks for the information. I should have added in the post that I've used the package on the office computer (windows 10) and it worked fine. The error only occurs on my laptop (windows 7). I thought the issue might be my home network, so I logged into McMaster's server from home through VPN, and got the same errors as before. And yes, running your example works on my office computer but not my laptop. 

On a side note, thanks for creating this package! Navigating ECCC's website can be a pain.

Comment: Ugh it's so frustrating, I have no idea why some computers are fine and some are not. I'll post an answer here if I figure it out.

Comment: Updated the answer with a possible solution!