# Repeated timeouts when trying to scrape XML Data to a datatable (fatal SSL/TLS alert)

Tags: r, xml, rvest

I'm trying to scrape xml data into a dataframe from this website:

https://www.dmo.gov.uk/data/XmlDataReport?reportCode=D1A

I would like to achieve dt in the following format:
[image]

However my code keeps throwing up errors all over the place:
Such as: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") :  Timeout was reached: [www.dmo.gov.uk] Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds`

Code is below:

```
library(data.table)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url <- read_html("https://www.dmo.gov.uk/data/XmlDataReport?reportCode=D1A")
dt <- rbindlist(lapply(url %>% html_nodes(css = "body > View_GILTS_IN_ISSUE > View_GILTS_IN_ISSUE") %>% 
                         xml_attrs(), 
                       function(x) as.data.table(t((x)))))
dt <- cbind(dt[,9, with = TRUE], 
            as.data.table(lapply(dt[,-9, with = TRUE], as.character)))
dt
```

Does anyone have any advice on how I can take this to completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first tried I fell at the first hurdle of actually downloading the file. I was consistently getting the error message: `fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed)`

I eventually found a solution here [Error running weathercan package - fatal SSL/TLS alert (e.g. handshake failed))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147821/error-running-weathercan-package-fatal-ssl-tls-alert-e-g-handshake-failed) which worked like a dream. I was then able to do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

x <- read_xml("http://www.dmo.gov.uk/data/XmlDataReport?reportCode=D1A")

zz <- x %>% xml_children() %>% xml_attrs() %>% enframe() %>% unnest_wider(value)
```

Which I think gives you exactly what you want except that it is a tibble rather than a data table.

[image]

Comment: Curious, even when trying that method I get the "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Timeout was reached: [www.dmo.gov.uk] Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds" message.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix the issue with a combination of mkpt_uk's answer, and the one available here: [Package "rvest" for web scraping https site with proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043172/package-rvest-for-web-scraping-https-site-with-proxy/38463559#38463559)

So downloading the file using:

```
download.file(url, destfile = destination)
```

followed by:

```
content <- read_xml(file)
```