# Problem with certificate on executing Curl

Tags: curl

for my job I'm trying to do a curl to call an api. There it is:

```
curl --insecure --cacert certificate.pem https://URL/api/v1/version/123/example
```

I passed the certificate but I have this error:

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.
```

I see the windows log event and I see this:

```
    The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The TLS connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.
 The SSPI client process is curl (PID: 20472).
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error running weathercan package - fatal SSL/TLS alert (e.g. handshake failed))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147821/error-running-weathercan-package-fatal-ssl-tls-alert-e-g-handshake-failed)